# Django Rest Framework Url Field Serializer

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a model named File which contains a field named 'url'.

```
class File(models.Model):
    """
    Generic File model
    """

    filename = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    url = models.URLField()
```

Now if I pass this URL :

```
 https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xyz/2018-09-25_17:39:16.80 (1).pdf
```

Note the space in the url before (1). The model serializer gives an error stating that the url is invalid.

Do I need to encode the url myself by replacing the space with '%20'

Comment: Have you tried doing so? It seems like this is a pretty easily testable situation.

Comment: Yes it does, was checking if that was a correct pythonic rest framework approach

Answer (score 2):

First of all, generate files without whitespaces if possible. That would be a better solution.
If it's not possible, change the **`URLField()`** to **`CharField()`**, which will compromise the ***URL Validation***. But, it's possible to use as a *valid url*.

If you still want to use **`URLField()`**, [write a custom validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/validators/#writing-validators) and add it via **`validator`** parameter

```
def custom_url_validator(value):
    # your validation

class File(models.Model):
    """
    Generic File model
    """

    filename = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    url = models.URLField(validators=[custom_url_validator,])
```

Comment: don't think this works because drf appends the default validator anyway